# Spring data Cassandra @Indexed annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-cassandra

I was working on Spring data Cassandra While creating an entity I am giving the required annotations for fields but when I am giving @Indexed annotation for creating an secondary index in the Schema and I am not able to query on the indexed attribute with out giving Allow Filtering.Could some one please tell me how to create a Secondary Index using Spring data annotations in Cassandra

```
This is the sample cod that I am using creating a Sprind data Cassandra Entity.@Indexed annotation not creating a secondary index in Cassandra database

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.UserDefinedType;
import com.datastax.driver.core.DataType;
import com.suntecgroup.xelerate.platform.demo.config.SpringContainer;
import com.suntecgroup.xelerate.platform.demo.store.CustomerCassandraStore;
import com.suntecgroup.xelerate.platform.demo.store.impl.CustomerCassandraStoreImpl;

@Table(value="CustomerCassandra")
public class CustomerCassandra extends CassandraEntity<Integer> {

    @PrimaryKey(value="cust_id")
    private Integer custId;
    @Indexed(value="name")
    private String name;
    @Indexed(value="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(value="domain")
    private String domain;
    @Column(value="category")
    private String category;
    @Column(value="created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    @CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.LIST,typeArguments = { DataType.Name.UDT }, userTypeName = "address_demo_type") 
    @Column(value="addresses")
    private List<Address> addresses;
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return custId;
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.custId = id;
    }
    public static CustomerCassandraStore getStore() {
        return (CustomerCassandraStore) SpringContainer.getBean(CustomerCassandraStoreImpl.class);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Address... addresses) {
        LinkedList<Address> addressList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(Address addr: addresses) {
            addressList.add(addr);
        }
        setAddresses(addressList);
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    @UserDefinedType(value="address_demo_type")
    public static class Address {

        @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT) 
        @Column(value="street_address")
        private String streetAddress;

        @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT) 
        @Column(value="city")   
        private String city;

        @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT) 
        @Column(value="country")    
        private String country;

        @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT) 
        @Column(value="pincode")    
        private String pincode;

        public String getStreetAddress() {
            return streetAddress;
        }
        public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
            this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        }
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }
        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }
        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }
        public String getPincode() {
            return pincode;
        }
        public void setPincode(String pincode) {
            this.pincode = pincode;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((pincode == null) ? 0 : pincode.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((streetAddress == null) ? 0 : streetAddress.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Address other = (Address) obj;
            if (city == null) {
                if (other.city != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
                return false;
            if (country == null) {
                if (other.country != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
                return false;
            if (pincode == null) {
                if (other.pincode != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!pincode.equals(other.pincode))
                return false;
            if (streetAddress == null) {
                if (other.streetAddress != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!streetAddress.equals(other.streetAddress))
                return false;
            return true;
        }}




}
```

Comment: Could you add the code that does not work? Or what you tried?

Comment: M.Mimpen Could you please check the code now and tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some bug in spring-data-cassandra lib. I'm not able to create index through annotation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while creating the schema during test execution (it's not clear how the OP creates the table based on the annotations).

My code was invoking `CassandraAdminOperations.createTable()` function and I quickly found out that `createTable` does not include indices, so any queries on the (supposedly) indexed columns were failing. My original code was just:

```java
@Autowired
private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;

@Before
public void createTable() {
    adminTemplate.createTable(true, CqlIdentifier.of(DATA_TABLE_NAME), User.class, new HashMap<>());
}
```

In order to generate the indices based on the annotations, I had to modify my `@Before` method as:

```java
@Autowired
private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;

@Before
public void createTable() {
    adminTemplate.createTable(true, CqlIdentifier.of(DATA_TABLE_NAME), User.class, new HashMap<>());
    CassandraPersistentEntity<?> entity = adminTemplate.getConverter().getMappingContext().getRequiredPersistentEntity(User.class);
    List<CreateIndexSpecification> indexSpecifications = adminTemplate.getConverter().getMappingContext().getCreateIndexSpecificationsFor(entity);
    indexSpecifications.forEach(is -> adminTemplate.getCqlOperations().execute((CreateIndexCqlGenerator.toCql(is))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table tableAnno=AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(MessagePO.class, Table.class);
    String tableName=tableAnno.value();
    log.info("initial table{}",tableName);
    /**
     * create table
     */
    adminTemplate.createTable(true, CqlIdentifier.fromCql(tableName), MessagePO.class, null);
    Field[] fields = MessagePO.class.getDeclaredFields();

    /**
     * create index
     */
    CqlOperations cqlOperations=adminTemplate.getCqlOperations();
    Arrays.stream(fields).forEach(field -> {
        Indexed indexed = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(field, Indexed.class);
        Column column = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(field, Column.class);
        if (indexed != null && column != null) {
            String indexVal = indexed.value();
            String indexSql=String.format("CREATE INDEX %s on %s(%s)",indexVal,tableName,column.value());
            cqlOperations.execute(String.format("DROP INDEX if EXISTS %s",indexVal));
            cqlOperations.execute(indexSql);
            log.info("create index {}",indexSql);
        }
    });
```

this is my initial index code, it's work well